# Problems using Proxy Protocol with AWS CLB

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-elb

I have a node app that uses SNI to direct requests to other servers / handle SSL certificates. It runs on EC2 web servers that sit behind a classic load balancer.  I now have a need for the client IP.  For years it has been working with these listeners:

```
            "ListenerDescriptions": [
            {
                "Listener": {
                    "Protocol": "TCP",
                    "LoadBalancerPort": 443,
                    "InstanceProtocol": "TCP",
                    "InstancePort": 443
                },
                "PolicyNames": []
            },
            {
                "Listener": {
                    "Protocol": "HTTP",
                    "LoadBalancerPort": 80,
                    "InstanceProtocol": "HTTP",
                    "InstancePort": 80
                },
                "PolicyNames": []
            }
        ],
```

According to [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/using-elb-listenerconfig-quickref.html) TCP supports proxy protocol, but when I enable it using `aws elb set-load-balancer-policies-for-backend-server --load-balancer-name testing --instance-port 443 --policy-names <my-ProxyProtocol-policy>` I get a response from curl -v of

```
$ curl -v https://www.example.org
*   Trying nn.nn.nn.nn:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to www.example.org (nn.nn.nn.nn) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to www.example.org:443 
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to www.example.org:443
```

Without the request reaching my node app.  I cannot figure out a way round this that enables me to host multiple domains on my servers using SSL.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Use curl with the -v flag for a more verbose output. This can give you more details about the SSL handshake process and where it's failing.